# Swift reload collection view not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am new to swift. I follow some tutorial to develop social application like twitter application to follow the [tutorial](https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course/Twitter). I start implement to follow button functions. its call the the another API call but same response come with minor modification(e.g - number of follower property increase by one). call also perfectly working. but collection view did not reload.my code is.

**ViewConroller**

```
import LBTAComponents
import TRON
import SwiftyJSON

class HomeDatasourceController: DatasourceController {

    let errorMessageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Apologies something went wrong. Please try again later..."
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.isHidden = true
        return label
    }()

    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    func follow(){
    print("inside controller")
    Service.sharedInstance.fetchfollowHomeFeed { (homeDatasource, err) in
    if let err = err {
        self.errorMessageLabel.isHidden = false

    if let apiError = err as? APIError<Service.JSONError> {

    if apiError.response?.statusCode != 200 {
    self.errorMessageLabel.text = "Status code was not 200"
    }
    }

    return
    }
    self.datasource = homeDatasource
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(errorMessageLabel)
        errorMessageLabel.fillSuperview() //LBTA method call

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 232, g: 236, b: 241)

        setupNavigationBarItems()

        Service.sharedInstance.fetchHomeFeed { (homeDatasource, err) in
            if let err = err {
                self.errorMessageLabel.isHidden = false

                if let apiError = err as? APIError<Service.JSONError> {

                    if apiError.response?.statusCode != 200 {
                        self.errorMessageLabel.text = "Status code was not 200"
                    }
                }

                return
            }

            self.datasource = homeDatasource
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        //first section of users
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            guard let user = self.datasource?.item(indexPath) as? User else { return .zero }

            let estimatedHeight = estimatedHeightForText(user.bioText)
            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedHeight + 66)
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            //our tweets size estimation

            guard let tweet = datasource?.item(indexPath) as? Tweet else { return .zero }

            let estimatedHeight = estimatedHeightForText(tweet.message)

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedHeight + 74)
        }


        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }

    private func estimatedHeightForText(_ text: String) -> CGFloat {
        let approximateWidthOfBioTextView = view.frame.width - 12 - 50 - 12 - 2
        let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfBioTextView, height: 1000)
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)]

        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)

        return estimatedFrame.height
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 1 {
            return .zero
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 1 {
            return .zero
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 64)
    }

}
```

**DataSource**

```
import LBTAComponents
import TRON
import SwiftyJSON

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == JSON {
    func decode<T: JSONDecodable>() throws -> [T] {
        return try map{try T(json: $0)}
    }
}

class HomeDatasource: Datasource, JSONDecodable {

    let users: [User]

    required init(json: JSON) throws {
        guard let usersJsonArray = json["users"].array, let tweetsJsonArray = json["tweets"].array else {
            throw NSError(domain: "com.letsbuildthatapp", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Parsing JSON was not valid."])
        }

//        self.users = usersJsonArray.map{User(json: $0)}
//        self.tweets = tweetsJsonArray.map{Tweet(json: $0)}

        self.users = try usersJsonArray.decode()
        self.tweets = try tweetsJsonArray.decode()

    }

    let tweets: [Tweet]

    override func footerClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type]? {
        return [UserFooter.self]
    }

    override func headerClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type]? {
        return [UserHeader.self]
    }

    override func cellClasses() -> [DatasourceCell.Type] {
        return [UserCell.self, TweetCell.self]
    }

    override func item(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any? {
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return tweets[indexPath.item]
        }
        return users[indexPath.item]
    }

    override func numberOfSections() -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func numberOfItems(_ section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 1 {
            return tweets.count
        }
        return users.count
    }

}
```

DataCell

```
import LBTAComponents

class UserCell: DatasourceCell {

    override var datasourceItem: Any? {
        didSet {
            guard let user = datasourceItem as? User else { return }
            followButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(follow), for: .touchUpInside)
            nameLabel.text = user.name
            usernameLabel.text = user.username
            bioTextView.text = user.bioText

            profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: user.profileImageUrl)
        }
    }

    let profileImageView: CachedImageView = {
        let imageView = CachedImageView()
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "profile_image")
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Brian Voong"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "@buildthatapp"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textColor = UIColor(r: 130, g: 130, b: 130)
        return label
    }()

    let bioTextView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = "iPhone, iPad, iOS Programming Community. Join us to learn Swift, Objective-C and build iOS apps!"
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return textView
    }()

    let followButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.borderColor = twitterBlue.cgColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.setTitleColor(twitterBlue, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "follow"), for: .normal)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        //        button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets
        return button
    }()
    func follow(){
        print("inside source")
        var link = HomeDatasourceController()
        link.follow()
    }
    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()

        backgroundColor = .white

        separatorLineView.isHidden = false
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 230, g: 230, b: 230)

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(usernameLabel)
        addSubview(bioTextView)
        addSubview(followButton)

        profileImageView.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 12, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 50, heightConstant: 50)

        nameLabel.anchor(profileImageView.topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: followButton.leftAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 8, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 20)

        usernameLabel.anchor(nameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: nameLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nameLabel.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 20)

        bioTextView.anchor(usernameLabel.bottomAnchor, left: usernameLabel.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: -4, leftConstant: -4, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

        followButton.anchor(topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 12, widthConstant: 120, heightConstant: 34)
    }
}
```

It using [LBTA components](https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents).i tried `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` but its not reloaded. Please help me to fix this problem.download my full source code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mt4McHSy1naotrYg6G1axaz6nCEzqyY-/view?usp=sharing) Please help me

Comment: Where's your attempt to reload the collection view?

Comment: @rmaddy after `self.datasource = homeDatasource` but it not reload see my complete code.

Comment: You need to post relevant code in your question.

Comment: I share the full source code. yo can find with this link "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mt4McHSy1naotrYg6G1axaz6nCEzqyY-/view?usp=sharing"

Comment: The preview link isn't working properly, but I'm assuming your reloadData code is outside your async block thus the failure to reload. As rmaddy said, you really need to post all the relevant code here.

Comment: @rmaddy  see my edit

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott see my edit

Comment: Any one give any solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your project and found issue which you did.
In class UserCell.swift, you should use next code:

```
func follow(){
    print("inside source")
    guard let link = controller as? HomeDatasourceController else { return }
    link.follow()
}
```

**Explaining issue**

It's your code that was in your project

```
func follow(){
    print("inside source")
    var link = HomeDatasourceController() // in this place you create a new local instance of class 'HomeDatasourceController'
    link.follow()
}
```